# I can't make a simple example of Scala Play db work

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Firstly, I've never worked with a database in Scala Play Framework. I did a research and found that the only way(?) to work with it is using a plain SQL. Is that so? I wonder, isn't there a way to do that the same way I can do that in RoR using models? At least, I found a plenty of examples showing, even encouraging working with plain SQL.

Secondly, I can't compile the code from the official documentation:

```
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
val result:Boolean = SQL("Select 1").execute()    //SQL is not found
```

Also, where is `SQL` located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing `anorm._` should fix the issue.

`SQL` is located in the package object `anorm`

Btw, `SQL` does not work without the sql connection, so wrap it like this:

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("select 1").execute()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the sql dependency to your project as described in the docs?

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaDatabase

Comment: then you should find SQL at anorm.SQL - ah, serejja just answered the same before